# Are named URLs in Django really necessary?

Tags: django

The URL mappings I used in my Django applications are "named URLs" as follows (according to Django's documents). For example,

in the project's *urls.py*:

```
path('main/', include('main.urls', namespace='main')),
```

and in the `main` app's *urls.py*:

```
path('', views.main, name='main'),
```

With the above `namespace` and `name` settings, the following formats may be used in views and templates, respectively:

```
reverse('main:main')
{% url 'main:main' %}
```

One of the advantages of using named URLs is that we may easily change the URL mappings without affecting the codes in views or templates.

I have developed dozens of real business Django projects. The above may sound reasonable, but I have never changed the URL settings in any of my projects. I wondered what kinds of projects will change the URL mappings from time to time so the named URLs are useful?

Comment: It is not that much about changing URLs. It deals with *escaping* strings in URLs, and avoiding complicated string processing as well. Furthermore people tend to write `foo`, instead of `/foo`, and thus that means that it will not per se create URLs where the browser will start at the root. Finally it makes it very clean to what the URL is pointing, instead of having to do the "decoding" yourself.

Comment: Have you ever done some i18n stuff in your Urls ?

Comment: I've done i18n on my websites, but not in the Urls. Would you give some examples of the usefulness of named Urls for i18n?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem good points, thanks.